# PyOpenGL glReadPixels causes ctypes Argument error after final POINTER creation

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, pyopengl, opengl-extensions

I'm having a strange issue with pyopengl and its imports, below is a small test program cut out of a much larger one, but it is enough to show the problem. You need PyOpenGL installed, and if you run it as it is it shows a blank window, and if you click and drag it prints out some 0s. If you uncomment the line `HANDLE.final = True` below, then it stops working, see the traceback below.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from ctypes import POINTER
import sys

HANDLE = POINTER(None)
#HANDLE.final = True

def display():
    glutSwapBuffers()

glutInit(sys.argv)
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(400,400)
glutCreateWindow("GLUT Window")

glutDisplayFunc(display)

def readPx(x,y):
    data_all = glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_BYTE)
    print data_all

glutMotionFunc(readPx)

glutMainLoop()
```

With that line uncommented it does this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 130, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
  File "C:\Users\Robin\dev\ogl_bug\ogl_bug.py", line 19, in readPx
    data_all = glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_BYTE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\images.py", line 371, in glReadPixels
    imageData
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
ArgumentError: argument 7: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
GLUT Motion callback <function readPx at 0x02CC5830> with (238, 190),{} failed: returning None argument 7: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

In my bigger program, this HANDLE code is buried 5 or 6 imports deep when trying to import OpenGL.raw.WGL._types, which is imported by any WGL Opengl extension but this is the smallest fragment that still causes the error.

I don't understand why the presence of this line is having an effect on a seemingly unrelated gl call - how can I use the load this extension without breaking other parts of PyOpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason - `POINTER(None)` gives back `ctypes.c_void_p`, which is a singleton, and means the `.final` attribute is visible gloablly after this import, presumable upsetting some type checking mechanism later.

It is fixed in the github version of PyopenGL. This is the commit:

https://github.com/mcfletch/pyopengl/commit/f087200406a37fc4b99eaad701d18bc64ded2d71

You can fix it in the current release of PyOpenGL by importing this small module before any OpenGL extensions:

```
import OpenGL.raw.WGL._types as t
from ctypes import _SimpleCData, _check_size

delattr(t.HANDLE, "final")

class HANDLE(_SimpleCData):
    _type_ = "P"

_check_size(HANDLE)

HANDLE.final = True

t.HANDLE = HANDLE
t.HGLRC = HANDLE
t.HDC = HANDLE

t.HPBUFFERARB = HANDLE
t.HPBUFFEREXT = HANDLE
```

This imports the PyOpenGL module that causes the problem, undoes the damage to `c_void_p`, then reassigns the `HANDLE` variable and its aliases to the `_SimpleCData` solution from the github link above.